# Reading from, Writing and Appending to JSON files

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing

I have been tryng to parse properly some json files for a while now, but I can't seem to get it right. I've tried many tutorials, and the json.net library but cannot seem to find the right way to go about this. My files all have the same format:

file.json:

```
{
  "Expense": {
    "Name": "something",
    "Amount": "34.90",
    "Due": "28/12/2011",
    "Recurrence": "1 Months",
    "Paid": "0",
    "LastPaid": "01/01/2002"
  }
}
{
  "Expense": {
    "Name": "OneTel Mobile Bill",
    "Amount": "39.90",
    "Due": "28/12/2011",
    "Recurrence": "1 Months",
    "Paid": "0",
    "LastPaid": "01/01/2002"
  }
}
{
  "Expense": {
    "Name": "some other Bill",
    "Amount": "44.90",
    "Due": "28/12/2011",
    "Recurrence": "1 Months",
    "Paid": "0",
    "LastPaid": "01/01/2002"
  }
}
```

Now, I have two problems here. But first, I *know* how to write json files. So that's not a problem for me. But my two problems are:

How to read the json string/file like:
(psuedocode)

```
FOREACH VAR EXPENSE IN EXPENSES 
OUTPUT EXPENSE.NAME 
OUTPUT EXPENSE.AMOUNT
```

etc etc...

And my second problem, is:

How to append a whole new "Expense" to an existing json file?

I would really appreciate your help on this.

Thank you

I am writing the json to the file like so:

```
    //Create the Json file and save it with WriteToFile();
    JObject jobject =
        new JObject(
            new JProperty("Expense",
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("Name", NameTextBox.Text),
                    new JProperty("Amount", AmountTextBox.Text),
                    new JProperty("Due", DueTextBox.Text),
                    new JProperty("Recurrence", EveryTextBox.Text + " " + EveryComboBox.SelectionBoxItem),
                    new JProperty("Paid", "0"),
                    new JProperty("LastPaid", "Never")
                            )
                        )
                   );            

    try
    {
        WriteToFile(Expenses, jobject.ToString());

        // Close the flyout now.
        this.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.Write(exception.Message);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you would have a much easier time if you created an Expense class and then serialized and read a collection of Expense objects (i.e. `List<Expense>`).

```
public class Expense
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Due { get; set; }
    public string Recurrence { get; set; }
    public decimal Paid { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastPaid{ get; set; }
}

public class ExpenseCollection : System.Collections.Generic.List<Expense>
{

}
```

You could then use the builtin [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class.

Rough code to create the JSON:

```
        ExpenseCollection cExpenses = new ExpenseCollection();
        // ToDo: Fill the expenses collection
        var sJSON = (new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer).Serialize(cExpenses);
        // ToDo: Write sJSON to a file
```

And to read it (note that this may need some tweaking):

```
        string sJSON;
        // ToDo: Read the json from a file
        ExpenseCollection cExpenses = (new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer).Deserialize<ExpenseCollection>(sJSON);
        // ToDo: Write sJSON to a file
```

Comment: Thank you @competent - I have read somewhere that I should serialize and read from List<> but not sure where to start. Could you please give me a head start? Are there tutorials you know of that I haven't found?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your JSON is formatted incorrectly, using the serialize method mentioned by @Competent_tech it would produce a result something like:

```
"Expense": [
  {
    "Name": "something",
    "Amount": "34.90",
    "Due": "28/12/2011",
    "Recurrence": "1 Months",
    "Paid": "0",
    "LastPaid": "01/01/2002"
 }
 {
    "Name": "OneTel Mobile Bill",
    "Amount": "39.90",
    "Due": "28/12/2011",
    "Recurrence": "1 Months",
    "Paid": "0",
    "LastPaid": "01/01/2002"
 }
 {
    "Name": "some other Bill",
    "Amount": "44.90",
    "Due": "28/12/2011",
    "Recurrence": "1 Months",
    "Paid": "0",
    "LastPaid": "01/01/2002"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, harag. But I don't know how to deserialize it? I've tried code samples and I can't get it to work. I don't know how to get the json file into a List<Expense> and then iterate through the list. @Competent's answer doesn't work because System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer() is not available in Windows Metro style apps. Could you please help?

And the code in

Comment: I've not done Windows Metro apps so not sure if I can help. I use the method @Competent mentioned. However maybe a 3rd party library can help, something like: http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. RE: that link you posted, that's what I'm currently using (as you might have noticed in my code example in my question) - unfortunately though, the Writers and Readers don't work in Metro apps because of the way you write to and read from files in Windows Developer Preview. It's way different now.